# Using 'predict.coxph' from the R package 'survival' in own R package

Tags: r, package, survival

I want to use the R package `survival` in my own R package.

My problem is that the function `predict.coxph` is not exported by `survival`, which is why I cannot use `survival::predict.coxph` listing survival under `Imports:` in the `DESCRIPTION` file.

Now I tried to list `survival` under `Depends:` and just use `predict(fittedmodel)` (and `coxph` and `Surv` without `survival::`). But I get the following `NOTEs` using `R CMD check --as-cran`:

1. "* checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE
   Package in Depends field not imported from: 'survival'
   These packages need to be imported from (in the NAMESPACE file)
   for when this namespace is loaded but not attached."
2. "no visible global function definition for 'Surv'" etc.
3. "Undefined global functions or variables:
   Surv coxph survfit"

Regarding 1): I have `import(survival)` in the `NAMESPACE` file.

What would be the problem here?

Comment: Do you also have "Imports: survival" in the DESCRIPTION  file?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Writing R Packages](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies) Manual

> Using foo:::f instead of foo::f allows access to unexported objects. This is generally not recommended, as the semantics of unexported objects may be changed by the package author in routine maintenance.

So there you have it. To access unexported functions, you just have to call them using `:::` instead of `::`, but be aware of the fact that those functions have no documentation available, so their use may change when new versions of the package in question is released.

About your dependencies issue, simply add `survival` to the `Imports` section of the `DESCRIPTION`.

Comment: Thanks! I have used `:::` now, but unfortunately I get: "* checking dependencies in R code ... WARNING
Unexported object imported by a ':::' call: 'survival:::predict.coxph'
  See the note in ?::: about the use of this operator.
  Including base/recommended package(s):
  'survival'". Would there be any other possibility? There should probably be a way to use `predict.coxph`, since `survival` is a very commonly used R package.

Comment: `predict.coxph` does have a help page. So it is an exception to the common practice of not including documentation for non-exported functions. I'm not able to explain why that function is not exported.